# May a pregnant woman eat non kosher food to satiate her craving?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, pregnancy-birth

An acquaintance of mine claimed that in the occasion of a craving of a particular non kosher food item, a pregnant woman would be permitted to consume it. Absent the food item, the woman and/or fetus would be brought to undue and injurious stress/harm.

His citation is his rabbi but this doesn’t seem credible. Is there any truth to this assertion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yoma 82a

> ת"ר עוברה שהריחה בשר קודש או בשר חזיר תוחבין לה כוש ברוטב ומניחין לה על פיה אם נתיישבה דעתה מוטב ואם לאו מאכילין אותה רוטב עצמה ואם נתיישבה דעתה מוטב ואם לאו מאכילין אותה שומן עצמו שאין לך דבר שעומד בפני פקוח נפש חוץ מע"ז וגילוי עריות ושפיכות דמים
>
> Our Rabbis taught: If a woman with child smelt the flesh of holy
>   flesh, or of pork, we put for her a reed into the juice and place it
>   upon her mouth.
>
> If thereupon she feels that her craving has been satisfied, it is
>   well.
>
> If not, one feeds her with the juice itself.
>
> If thereupon her craving is satisfied it is not one feeds her with the
>   fat meat itself, for there is nothing that can stand before [the duty
>   of] saving life with the exception of idolatry, incest(13) and
>   bloodshed [which are prohibited in all situations].

Reported in SA OC 617.2

> עוברה שהריחה (ופניה משתנים, אף על פי שלא אמרה "צריכה אני") (רבינו ירוחם נתיב כ"ז) -- לוחשין לה באזנה שיום הכיפורים הוא; אם נתקררה דעתה בזכרון זה -- מוטב, ואם לאו -- מאכילין אותה עד שתתישב דעתה. ‏

Comment: I do believe contemporary poskim disallow this since nowadays there are plenty of kosher alternatives to calm the crave

Comment: @sam nowadays is no different. it all depends on the situation. Back then too if there were alternatives they'd have used them first if possible.

Comment: @DoubleAA ,I saw it brought down by prominent posek,have to find it

Comment: @sam maybe he meant it's not as common nowadays?

Comment: @sam yeah please try to find it , the answer was wonderful but I remain skeptical contemporary poskim permit it